# document.[formName].[fieldName].value=" "; is not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Based on some check, am setting field values of the form to ""

I have below code Snippet.

```
if(Condition){
  --do Something
  }
else
{
document.form1.monthField.value="";
document.form1.dateField.value="";
document.form1.hoursField.vale="";
document.form1.minutesField.value="";
}
```

Am just setting all the fields to null (" ") in else block.

FYI :  monthField is drop down list, where user can choose any month[1 to 12]
Date and hours and Minutes fields follows the same.

This is working fine and am able to set " "  to the field in all other browsers except Mozilla.

Could anyone please help me? Is there any other way to do it in Mozilla?

Comment: If the code in the post is exactly what you have, I doubt it would work in any browser.

Comment: Agree with Teemu, That looks invalid with the period between the brackets, so it shouldn't work anywhere.

Comment: Thank you . I just gave brackets for better understanding. The code is      document.form1.firstname.value="";  I wonder why it's not working in Mozilla alone. I even put some alerts. I am able to see the alerts but the value is not setting.

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript code that is giving you the error? What you've posted is not enough to see the full scope of the problem.

Comment: @GregBurghardt  I updated the code here. I am able to reproduce the problem. I want to set the month field to null..... jsfiddle.net/vkreddyk9/KYvv4/5

Comment: Your JSFiddle is working fine. The text fields are blanked out, and the Month dropdown has "1" selected because that is the first option, and no `OPTION` has an empty string for a value.

Comment: Agreed Greg and thank you:) But for other browsers how it is working? Am just asking with my curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

the full syntax below should work:

> document.forms[formName].elements[fieldName].value = '';

Comment: Thank you @Nisanth.. I tried, But there seems to be syntax error.

Comment: Are you trying to set the value inside a loop?

Comment: No... I have If condition.

Answer (score 0):

i have created the sample jsfiddle using above logic. It is working fine in All the browsers.

```
document.test.month.value = "";
document.test.date.value = "";
document.test.hours.value = "";
document.test.minutes.value = "";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KYvv4/1/

Comment: Thanks Suresh. I updated the code here. I am able to reproduce the problem. I want to set the month field to ""    http://jsfiddle.net/vkreddyk9/KYvv4/5/

Comment: it looks not possible in firefox :)